# error npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR npm ERR! invalid json response body when installing reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, npm

I'm trying to learn ReactJS, but the ReactJS docs say *install with *

```
npx create-react-app {project_name}
```

it also required Node.js & npm. I have installed Node.js latest version & npm. But when I run the command, it always getting the same error, the error message says

```
npm ERR! code FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! errno FETCH_ERROR
npm ERR! invalid json response body at https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fsemver reason: Invalid response body while trying to fetch https://registry.npmjs.org/@types%2fsemver: EBUSY: resource busy or locked, rename 'C:\Users\AGUS\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\tmp\d5e89a99' -> 'C:\Users\AGUS\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_cacache\content-v2\sha512\5f\16\d22537befb8a38d3af73438bd2409a960900a502346287a0a0fa17784814bd2664f39eeb0107aa02ac292aeb51d7f52f4a90db5325d9b47bc8f5ce1538ca'

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\AGUS\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2022-11-02T08_20_55_473Z-debug-0.log
```

I have searched up this problem but its not solved, always error.
Please help me solve this problem :(

I have tried uninstall & reinstall node, still not working;
I tried `npm cache clean --force` & `npm cache verify` still not working.

Comment: Sometimes the issue is their cause of network bandwidth try using `npm cache clean --force` If it doesn't work do it again after a while

Comment: @MeetBhalodiya i've had this error for 3 days now, i told you, `npm cache clean --force` didnt woked.

Answer (score 1):

Try :

```
 npm cache verify

 npx create-react-app {project_name}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and these steps solved it.

✓ Would you like to use `src/` directory with this project? **Yes**

✓ Would you like to use experimental `app/` directory with this project?  **Yes**

✓ What import alias would you like configured? ... @/*

And also ensure that no background apps are running.